# Speech To Text Singleton Class in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am using this [library](https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text) for stt.

it says that

> Initialize once
>
> The initialize method only needs to be called once per application
> session. After that listen, start, stop, and cancel can be used to
> interact with the plugin. Subsequent calls to initialize are ignored
> which is safe but does mean that the onStatus and onError callbacks
> cannot be reset after the first call to initialize. For that reason
> there should be only one instance of the plugin per application. The
> SpeechToTextProvider is one way to create a single instance and easily
> reuse it in multiple widgets.

my code:

```
final SpeechToText speech = SpeechToText();
SpeechToTextProvider? speechProvider;

Future<void> initSpeechState() async {
    await speechProvider?.initialize();
  }

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    speechProvider = SpeechToTextProvider(speech);
    initSpeechState();
}
```

The problem is that i define this in my root state and it works good in ios and android but this initializing method ask permissions from app launch state in ios side. What i would like to do is it should ask permissions (recognition, microphone) in the speech to text screen. Can i define this provider in a singleton and call it whenever i need this provider? It should initialize only once for per appliciation session.

Answer (score 0):

Use [isAvailable](https://pub.dev/documentation/speech_to_text/latest/speech_to_text_provider/SpeechToTextProvider/isAvailable.html) property to check if the provider has already been initialized.